# dividing list in python based on variable

Tags: python

I am trying to split a python string based on time.

I have several variables with times associated with them:

factor 1 = 10 minutes

factor 2 = 2 minutes

factor 3 = 8 minutes

factor 4 = 20 minutes

factor 5 = 7 minutes

i want to be able to ask python to split the factors into 2 substrings based on time. For instance I only have 19 minutes so I want python to divide my string into:

string 1 = ["factor 1", "factor 2", "factor 5"]

string 2 would then have the remaining factors.

i want to be able to give python a time and for it to spit out a string which is closest to this time.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Its a dynamic programming problem. Google for coin change dynamic programming.

Comment: It actually looks like a knapsack problem, though it's hard to tell. Well done to those who divined the intention, and I've deleted my answer since I totally misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok this code is just wrote , you can give it a try :

I suppose you use variables like that :

```
factors = {"factor 1" : "10 minutes",
"factor 2" : "2 minutes",
"factor 3" : "8 minutes",
"factor 4" : "20 minutes",
"factor 5" : "7 minutes"
}

wantedTime = 19;
String_1={}
String_2={}
total = 0
for k,v in factors.items():## or factors.iteritems()
    time = int(v.split(" ")[0])
    if total+time <= wantedTime:
        total +=time
        String_1[k]=v
    else:
        String_2[k]=v
```

Comment: This doesn't run as it is. You need to have `for k, v in factors.items()`

Comment: Is there a way to randomise the list of factors so that it doesnt always select the same ones first? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the combination of which the sum of time equals to 19. You may want to look into `itertools`:

```
import itertools
factor_list=['factor 1 = 10 minutes',
    'factor 2 = 2 minutes',
    'factor 3 = 8 minutes',
    'factor 4 = 20 minutes',
    'factor 5 = 7 minutes']
resultlist=[]
for r in range(len(factor_list)):
    for factor in itertools.combinations(factor_list, r):
        if sum([int(item[item.index('=')+2:item.index(' minutes')]) for item in factor])==19:
            print factor

('factor 1 = 10 minutes', 'factor 2 = 2 minutes', 'factor 5 = 7 minutes')
```